# Find example for probabilities.

Tags: probability

Find example such that $P(A)=P(B)=\frac23$ and $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.
I can't deal with it. Can you help me?

Comment: What does $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ imply about the events $A$ and $B$?  It implies that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  What are some prototypical examples of independent events that you have seen so far?  Perhaps something to do with random elements in board games?  Can you construct an example where $A$ and $B$ both have probability $2/3$ yet are still independent?

Comment: DId you try one thing at a time? What is an example such that $P(A)=\frac23$, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an urn with $9$ balls numbered from 1 to 9 where you have to extract one ball.

Let $A$ be the event "extract a number in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$". Then $P(A)=6/9=2/3$.

Let $B$ be the event "extract a number in $\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}$". Then $P(B)=6/9=2/3$.

Moreover $A\cap B=\{3,4,5,6\}$ and  $P(A\cap B)=4/9=(2/3)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Think about a random x in this square identified by its row and column.

```
x x x  
x x x  
x x x
```